# 'selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: u'chrome not reachable

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using webdriver to config a router, but when I run script:

```
from selenium import webdriver
self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
```

It opens chrome and no response, and then raise exception:

> chrome not reachable.

My computer has two network cards, when I forbbiden one, it works well. 
I don't konw why, please help!

Answer (score 7):

In pure case "chrome not reachable" means that Chrome binary can be started but debugging port is not reachable.

Debugging port is set by argument: --remote-debugging-port=12582

In my case it happens because some issues with sand-box:

```
ps afvvx | grep chrome

/opt/google/chrome/chrome --disable-background-networking --disable-client-side-phishing
21026 pts/2    S+     0:00      0    47  6008   100  0.0  |           \_ cat
21027 pts/2    S+     0:00      0    47  6008   100  0.0  |           \_ cat
21029 pts/2    Z+     0:00      0     0     0     0  0.0  |           \_ [chrome-sandbox] <defunct>
```

When I run /opt/google/chrome/chrome-sandbox

```
# /opt/google/chrome/chrome-sandbox  -h
The setuid sandbox provides API version 1, but you need 0
Please read [https://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/LinuxSUIDSandboxDevelopment][1].

close: Bad file descriptor
Read on socketpair: Success
```

From url above I can't get what I'll to do to fix SUID SandBox, but it can be switched off by Chrome arg --disable-setuid-sandbox(sometimes with --no-sandbox):

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver

from xvfbwrapper import Xvfb

vdisplay = Xvfb()
vdisplay.start()

from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-setuid-sandbox")

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/local/sbin/chromedriver', chrome_options=chrome_options)  # Optional argument, if not specified will search path.
driver.get('http://www.google.com/xhtml');
time.sleep(5) # Let the user actually see something!
search_box = driver.find_element_by_name('q')
search_box.send_keys('ChromeDriver')
search_box.submit()
time.sleep(5) # Let the user actually see something!
driver.quit()

vdisplay.stop()
```

Answer (score 1):

Another case it's when some package is not installed like dbus-X11:

```
/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome --no-sandbox --disable-setuid-sandbox --disable-background-networking --disable-client-side-phishing-detection --disable-component-update --disable-default-apps --disable-hang-monitor --disable-prompt-on-repost --disable-sync --disable-web-resources --enable-logging --ignore-certificate-errors --load-extension=/tmp/.com.google.Chrome.a0gQAp/internal --log-level=0 --metrics-recording-only --no-first-run --password-store=basic --remote-debugging-port=12512 --safebrowsing-disable-auto-update --safebrowsing-disable-download-protection --test-type=webdriver --use-mock-keychain --user-data-dir=/tmp/.com.google.Chrome.dgq4j1 data:,
[39330:39330:0501/130308:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(185)] Running without the SUID sandbox! See https://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/LinuxSUIDSandboxDevelopment for more information on developing with the sandbox on.
Xlib:  extension "RANDR" missing on display ":1070".
Xlib:  extension "RANDR" missing on display ":1070".
[39330:39330:0501/130308:ERROR:desktop_window_tree_host_x11.cc(830)] Not implemented reached in virtual void views::DesktopWindowTreeHostX11::InitModalType(ui::ModalType)

(google-chrome:39330): GConf-WARNING **: Client failed to connect to the D-BUS daemon:
/usr/bin/dbus-launch terminated abnormally without any error message
[39330:39353:0501/130308:ERROR:browser_gpu_channel_host_factory.cc(151)] Failed to create channel.
```

Just install it with:

```
apt-get install dbus-X11
```