# How to start Chrome with no display on linux with python Selenium?

Tags: python, linux, google-chrome, selenium, ssh

I have Linux on remote machine.
I tried to start set of selenium test via ssh but it is failed all the time

```
from selenium import webdriver
chromedriver = "/somepath/webdriver/chromedriver"
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)

selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.28.455506 (18f6627e265f442aeecasdasdasdadsad819aeeea1f),platform=Linux 4.4.34-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64 x86_64)
```

then I tried start it with Xvfb and pyvirtualdisplay

```
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from selenium import webdriver
display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
display.start()
chromedriver = "/somepath/webdriver/chromedriver"
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
```

but then I got error `selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: chrome not reachable`
How can I start Chrome via ssh on Linux with Python Selenium?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210765/any-way-to-start-google-chrome-in-headless-mode

Comment: or for this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29204780/selenium-common-exceptions-webdriverexception-message-uchrome-not-reachable

Comment: This is definitely not a duplicate. In first case we start chrome without selenium and python. In second case we use different one library and use Chrome Options.

Comment: maybe you should do: export DISPLAY=:<DISPLAYNUM> in bash script  eg. export DISPLAY=:101

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Any way to start Google Chrome in headless mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210765/any-way-to-start-google-chrome-in-headless-mode)