# How get the text values when webscraping with selenium?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping

I am webscraping a page. 
I get the element `<span class="product_content_brand"> NikeLab </span>`
with selenium on python3.

```
from selenium import webdriver


browser= webdriver.Chrome("/home/desarrollo10/Downloads/
chromedriver_linux64/chromedriver")

browser.get("https://theurge.com.au/")
C=browser.find_element_by_tag_name("a").click()
time.sleep(0.5)
D=browser.find_element_by_class_name("tag-filters_clearall").click()

S=browser.find_elements_by_class_name("product_content")

for s in S:
    print(s.text)
```

I want to get the text from the element with the class "product_content" and I am getting:

> WebDriverException: Message: chrome not reachable
>       (Session info: chrome=71.0.3578.98)
>       (Driver info: chromedriver=2.44.609551 
>       (5d576e9a44fe4c5b6a07e568f1ebc753f1214634),platform=Linux 4.15.0-43- 
>       generic x86_64)

Comment: Does Chrome open at all?

Comment: Are you sure chrome is at "/home/desarrollo10/Downloads/
chromedriver_linux64/chromedriver"?

Comment: Yeah. The page open and I can watch it. If I write type(S), the result is "list"

Answer (score 0):

try possible solution found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29204780/selenium-common-exceptions-webdriverexception-message-uchrome-not-reachable) about adding a couple of arguments (no-sandbox, disable-setuid-sandbox) when starting up Chrome:

```
chrome_options = Options()
#argument to switch off suid sandBox and no sandBox in Chrome 
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-setuid-sandbox")

browser= webdriver.Chrome("/home/desarrollo10/Downloads/chromedriver_linux64/chromedriver", chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

Then also:

I'm not seeing `class = "tag-filters_clearall"`, but rather `class = "tag-filters_clear-all"`

So I think you meant to have:

```
D=browser.find_element_by_class_name("tag-filters_clear-all").click()
```

not:

```
D=browser.find_element_by_class_name("tag-filters_clearall").click()
```

Comment: This makes sense... but why is the error `WebDriverException: Message: chrome not reachable`?

Comment: Thanks,You is right. I have done this correction but, I cannot get the atribute text.